# Special case of useState, what is this?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, supabase

I'm doing react-native project with expo + supabase.

From its QuickStart docs, (https://supabase.com/docs/guides/with-expo#launch)

```js
import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { supabase } from './lib/supabase'
import Auth from './components/Auth'
import Account from './components/Account'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { Session } from '@supabase/supabase-js'

export default function App() {
  const [session, setSession] = (useState < Session) | (null > null)  // <-- what is this?

  useEffect(() => {
    setSession(supabase.auth.session())

    supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((_event, session) => {
      setSession(session)
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <View>
      {session && session.user ? (
        <Account key={session.user.id} session={session} />
      ) : (
        <Auth />
      )}
    </View>
  )
}
```

I can't figure out how this `useState` works.

I know that `|` is bit-wise OR operator, but how does this work with useState?

Comment: I would read it as normal useState where you set type of state to Session or null and default value is null. But it's my first time seeing this syntax.

Comment: I have never seen anything like that before in my life, are you sure that's actually valid code?

Comment: I also haven't seen anything like this. does it works without any runtime error? (null > null) this doesn't make sense. where did you get this template?

Comment: @FazleRabbiAdor it is in the posts url docs. I guess they have miscopied from editor to docs based on first answer.

Comment: I have made a PR to fix this typo in the docs

Comment: Update: this typo is fixed in the docs from my [PR](https://github.com/supabase/supabase/pull/8360)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would happen when you paste typescript code into a `.js` file and your editor tries to format it and fails miserably.

I think the code actually intended to be this.

```
const [session, setSession] = useState<Session|null>(null);
```

The extra brackets and space was added by your editor. VSCode does this for instance.

The above statement means that `session` is a state variable which can be of type `Session` or `null`. And you initialise it with the value `null`.

Here is a [link](https://www.carlrippon.com/typed-usestate-with-typescript/) to help you use TS with `useState`.

Comment: https://github.com/supabase/supabase/issues/8359

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in `useState` here, try below code

```
const [session, setSession] = (useState <Session | null>(null);  // updated here <Session | null>
```

is the interface which is used in typescript, For easy to use remove the Interface if you don't understand.